# How to simulate an user click to a listview item in junit testing?

Tags: android, android-listview, junit

I am try to write a junit test case on selecting a list item and intent to next activity, but i dont know how to simulate this user action by junit coding. Can anyone help?

Also i wanna ask, is there any material teaching the function or syntax on simlate different user action in junit?

The following is a example from my school tutorial notes, and i want to do something like this one, but on a listview item.

```
public void testKilosToPounds() { 

 /* INTERACTIONS */ 
 TouchUtils.tapView(this, textKilos); // tap the EditText textKilos 
 sendKeys("1"); // sent the number 1 
 TouchUtils.clickView(this, buttonPounds); // click the button buttonPounds 

 /*CHECK THE RESULT*/ 
 double pounds; 
 try { 
 pounds = Double.parseDouble(textPounds.getText().toString()); 
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
 pounds = -1; 
 } 

 //JUnit Assert equals 

 // message expected actual delta for comparing doubles 
 assertEquals("1 kilo is 2.20462262 pounds", 2.20462262, pounds, DELTA); 
 }
```

Comment: Are you using [instrumentation tests](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html) as opposed to something like Robolectric?

Comment: Sorry, i dont know what you mean. @marcus.ramsden

Comment: Just trying to nail down a bit more on the problem. Under Android junit testing is a pretty broad term, are you trying to use something like [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html)?

Comment: I want to perform some user action by coding, i hope this link can help you understand whats my problem was.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html 
 
 @marcus.ramsden

Comment: Ah ok, I don't really have much experience with TouchUtils, but an alternative to using TouchUtils might be the `AbsListView.performItemClick` method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick(android.view.View, int, long)). Just grab the listview in your testcase then call that method on it.

Comment: I edited my question with some additional code, hope its help
@marcus.ramsden

Comment: Ok, you provided alternative solution to me, i try this later. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am working on JUnit from last few months to test android applications. And so i am now able to test almost things like webservices and views. Anyway i am sharing my code to test listview with item click and in next activity(InfoActivity) to check data that i sent using intent. InfoActivity is activity where i am sending data of clicked item from ListActivity.

```
public class ListActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ListActivity> {

private Activity activity;
private ListView lv;
private InfoActivity contextInfoActivity;
private TextView tvInfo;

public  ListActivityTest(){
    super(ListActivity.class);
}



@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    activity = (ListActivity)getActivity();
    lv = (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.lv);

}

public void testCase1(){
    assertNotNull(activity);
    assertNotNull(lv);
}

public void testCase2(){

    Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(InfoActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            lv.performItemClick(lv,4,0);
            //lv is listview,4 is item position,0 is default id
        }
    });

    Activity currentActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitor(monitor);
    contextInfoActivity = (InfoActivity) currentActivity;

    assertNotNull(contextInfoActivity);
    tvInfo = (TextView)contextInfoActivity.findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

    assertNotNull(tvInfo);
    assertEquals("Karan",tvInfo.getText().toString());
    //karan is name at position 4 in listview and i am checking it with name set in textview of next activity i.e infoActivity.

}


@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();

    activity = null;
    lv = null;
    tvInfo = null;
    contextInfoActivity = null;

}
```

Hope this ll b helpfull for you.I you want to ask something feel free to ask.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can click on a specific row in a `ListView` by first getting the View that holds that child, and then passing that view in to `TouchUtils.clickView`.

If you have a `ListView view` and `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 this`, and you want to click position `p` in the view:

```
TouchUtils.clickView(this, view.getChildAt(p));
```

You probably also want to check if the view is actually on screen too.